# Как сложить все заначения временных отрезков datetime.timedelta в списоке?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Есть список:

```
p = [datetime.timedelta(seconds=856), datetime.timedelta(seconds=5937), 
     datetime.timedelta(seconds=3447), datetime.timedelta(seconds=3061), 
     datetime.timedelta(seconds=1201), datetime.timedelta(seconds=158), 
     datetime.timedelta(seconds=2233), datetime.timedelta(seconds=1505), 
     datetime.timedelta(seconds=3351), datetime.timedelta(seconds=2762), 
     datetime.timedelta(seconds=1813), datetime.timedelta(seconds=83)]
```

При переборе списка данные:

```
0:14:16 
1:38:57
0:57:27
0:51:01
0:20:01
0:02:38
0:37:13
0:25:05
0:55:51
0:46:02
0:30:13
0:01:23
```

Как осуществить сложение всех временных отрезков?

То есть, чтобы на выходе операции получить `7:20`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4049857/13794578

Comment: хм, что то я поторопился с вопросом и не догуглил, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

По [ссылке из комментария @5c0rp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163792/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-datetime-timedelta#comment2019507_1163792) можно найти такое решение:

```
res = sum(p, datetime.timedelta())
print(res)
>>>7:20:07
```

Docstring функции `sum()`:

> ```
> In [16]: sum?
> Signature: sum(iterable, start=0, /)
> Docstring:
> Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
>
> When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
> This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
> reject non-numeric types.
> Type:      builtin_function_or_method
> ```

Обратите внимание на параметр `start=0`, принимающий по умолчанию значение `0`. Именно это вызывает ошибку (`0` - числовой литерал типа `int`):

```
In [17]: sum(p)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-654d70e1fa84> in <module>
----> 1 sum(p)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Поэтому, чтобы избежать данной ошибки, в качестве `start` нужно указать коструктор класса `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `reduce` и модулем `operator`. `reduce` по очереди будет брать значения из вашего массива и плюсовать следующий элемент с сумме предыдущих.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
q = reduce(operator.add, p)
print(q)
```